# Rhino Mocks: How to tell if object is mocked or real?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

Given an object `o`, how can I tell if it's a mocked or a *real* object?

The only way I can see doing this looks a bit hacky:

```
public bool IsMockedObject(object o)
{
  try
  {
    o.GetMockRepository();
    return true;
  }
  catch(InvalidOperationException)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Please tell me there's a better way!

Comment: Why would you need this? Properly done you shouldn't need this at all.

Comment: +1 for Jason. How complicated is your setup that you, the original author, can't even tell?

Comment: Jason, I would agree with you in general.  The case for this is basically duct taping legacy code that is slated for a long-term replacement project.  I'd still like to use unit testing for the legacy code as it is still maintained, so for certain circumstances the "properly done" approach is not always the most cost-effective approach.

Comment: In my case, I was creating a data setup scenario that could either use mocked or real objects (for integration tests). I would pass in a mocked sql session if I desired to just deal with things in memory or a not-mocked session if I wanted to do an integration test with everything saved to the db. This allows me to switch modes based on what is passed in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check if the object implements `IMockedObject`:

```
bool isMocked = o is Rhino.Mocks.Interfaces.IMockedObject;
```

This of course would require referencing the RhinoMocks assembly, which I would try to avoid for your production code.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!

And thanks for the advice, we only reference Rhino mocks for unit testing, which is in a project different than our production code.